# don't know Connection string parameter in C#

Tags: c#, sql

i am developing an application in C#,i have create database1.mdf by
right clicking on my project,add item
then creating a database.
my intial problem was,i was able to execute query correctly but those modification wasn't reflected in main database
finally after lot of surfing i changed copy to output directory to copy if newer but still i am not able to rectify my problem.

now i am feeling that i need to connect to sqlserver using connectionstring but i don't know username,servername,password etc...

can anyone help me please

Comment: You haven't posted nearly enough information for us to help you out.  Are you using SQL Server or SQL Compact?  If Server, which version?  We won't be able to tell you what your servername, username, password, etc are no matter what you post though.  Here's a great website to figure out what your connection string might be though for all different kinds of databases:  http://www.connectionstrings.com/  You really might just need to do some research on how to use databases though.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to connect database in csharp so visual studio will help you to connect with database

1. go to solution explorer right click on project and add new item and select         service-base database click add.
2. Now Go to Server explorer look there is database with .mdf extension 
   expand it right click on table and create table your self.
3. After creating table you need connection string to connect your application to database.
4. you connection string look like this

   string databaseFileName="Your database file with .mdf extension like database1.mdf";
   string connectionString=@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\"+databaseFileName+";Integrated Security=True";
5. SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
   conn.Open();
   Console.writeLine(conn.State.ToString());/*this will show your database state is open or close.

Note:Here i am using visual studion 2013 other (LocalDB)\v11.0 this could be changed .